# Improving performance of INotifyPropertyChanged affecting all items in a collection

Tags: performance, xamarin.forms, inotifypropertychanged

I have an `ObservableCollection` that's used as the `ItemsSource` of a [Xamarin Forms DataGrid](https://github.com/akgulebubekir/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid). The view models in the collection each have an observable `IsSelected` property, bound to a `Switch` in the data grid's row template. There can be something up to ~20k rows in this data grid.

There are buttons for "Select All" and "Select None", which do what you'd expect: they set this property to the appropriate value for *each element* in the collection. For large collections, this takes multiple seconds to complete, and the reason is handling all of those property change notifications to keep the UI in sync.

Is there a way to either batch these change notifications, or suspend them and update the UI the old-fashioned way, or do something else, that will improve the performance? Techniques I've seen for [batching `PropertyChanged` notifications](https://www.kolls.net/blog/?p=28) involve coalescing multiple changes to the same property on the same object, which is not a problem I have.

Comment: "up to ~20k rows" - I would strongly suggest reconsidering this.  Is a user on a mobile device honestly going to need 20k rows of data?  Can you at least virtualize the display so that only the visible rows are updated?

Comment: @Jason I do believe that a user in this problem domain needs access to their data when they're in the field, yes. "Virtualising the display" I think would require modifying the third-party DataGrid plugin, and is possible in principle, I was wondering whether there was a common pattern for it.

Comment: if that is truly a req I would look at a commercial component that supports virtualization and not the free one you're using

Comment: @Jason I've already asked if there's budget for that and been told no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

We always use **pagination** if we need to load large numbers of items . In your case you could update the next ten or more items' `IsSelected` before we add them to ItemsSource .

**Option 2:**

You can simply run multiple methods at a time. So that you could update the value of  `IsSelected` in  multiple methods (in each method you could update 1000 or more items)

```
// this process run synchronously.
Task.Run(() =>
{
// call your methods
MyFunction1(); // update 1-1000
MyFunction2(); // update 1001-2000 
});
```

```
// this process doesn't wait for function execution,it will run Asynchronous way.use this if you dont want to use function return value;
Task.Factory.StartNew(MyFunction1);
Task.Factory.StartNew(MyFunction2);
```

Both process help you to non blocking UI.

Comment: @Graham Lee  If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue